# Is there a way to change the size (and direction) of the step of the a:s:b function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matlab

What is the shortest way to get

```
x =

     2    -2     4    -4     6    -6     ...     14    -14    16   -16
```

I figured out two options, one of them somewhat short:

```
>>x=[];  
for k=2:2:16  
x=[x k -k];  
end  
x
```

However, I wonder if it's possible to affect size and direction of the `s` in `a:s:b`, since the sequence above can be constructed with a regular pattern: +2, -4, +6, -8, +10 etc. That would be even shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A two-line solution without a loop:

`xt = [2:2:16; -(2:2:16)]; 
 x = xt(:)'`

`xt` is 2 by 8. Since the `(:)` operation outputs it as a single column vector by concatenating each successive column of `xt`, the desired result is obtained by transposing.

Comment: Hohoo.... nice!

Answer (score 2):

Reshaping matrices may be another solution.

```
reshape([2:2:16; -(2:2:16)],1,16)
```